# How to Implement Patterns to Match Brute Force Login and Port Scanning Attacks using Flink CEP

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-batch

I have a use case where a large no of logs will be consumed to the apache flink CEP. My use case is to find the brute force attack and port scanning attack. The challenge here is that while in ordinary CEP we compare the value against a constant like "event" = login. In this case the Criteria is different as in the case of brute force attack we have the criteria as follows.

> username is constant and event="login failure" (Delimiter the event happens 5 times within 5 minutes).
> It means the logs with the login failure event is received for the same username 5 times within 5 minutes

And for port Scanning we have the following criteira.

> ip address is constant and dest port is variable (Delimiter is the event happens 10 times within 1 minute). It means the logs with  constant ip address is received for the  10 different ports within 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

With Flink, when you want to process the events for something like one username or one ip address in isolation, the way to do this is to partition the stream by a key, using `keyBy()`. The training materials in the Flink docs have a [section on Keyed Streams](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/etl.html#keyed-streams) that explains this part of the DataStream API in more detail. `keyBy()` is the roughly same concept as a `GROUP BY` in SQL, if that helps.

With CEP, if you first key the stream, then the pattern will be matched separately for each distinct value of the key, which is what you want.

However, rather than CEP, I would instead recommend Flink SQL, perhaps in combination with [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html), for this use case. MATCH_RECOGNIZE is a higher-level API, built on top of CEP, and it's easier to work with. In combination with SQL, the result is quite powerful.

You'll find some Flink SQL training materials and examples (including examples that use MATCH_RECOGNIZE) [in Ververica's github account](https://github.com/ververica/sql-training).

**Update**

To be clear, I wouldn't use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for these specific rules; neither it nor CEP is needed for this use case. I mentioned it in case you have other rules where it would be helpful. (My reason for not recommending CEP in this case is that implementing the distinct constraint might be messy.)

For example, for the port scanning case you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT e1.ip, COUNT(DISTINCT e2.port) 
FROM events e1, events e2 
WHERE e1.ip = e2.ip AND timestampDiff(MINUTE, e1.ts, e2.ts) < 1 
GROUP BY e1.ip HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e2.port) >= 10;
```

The login case is similar, but easier.

Note that when working with streaming SQL, you should give some thought to [state retention](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/query_configuration.html#idle-state-retention-time).

**Further update**

This query is likely to return a given IP address many times, but it's not desirable to generate multiple alerts.

This could be handled by inserting matching IP addresses into an Alert table, and only generate alerts for IPs that aren't already there.

Or the output of the SQL query could be processed by a de-duplicator implemented using the DataStream API, similar to the [example in the Flink docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/etl.html#an-example-with-keyed-state). If you only want to suppress duplicate alerts for some period of time, use a `KeyedProcessFunction` instead of a `RichFlatMapFunction`, and use a Timer to clear the state when it's time to re-enable alerts for a given IP.

**Yet another update (concerning CEP and distinctness)**

Implementing this with CEP should be possible. You'll want to key the stream by the IP address, and have a pattern that has to match within one minute.

The pattern can be roughly like this:

```java
Pattern<Event, ?> pattern = Pattern
  .<Event>begin("distinctPorts")
  .where(iterative condition 1)
  .oneOrMore()
  .followedBy("end")
  .where(iterative condition 2)
  .within(1 minute)
```

The first iterative condition returns true if the event being added to the pattern has a distinct port from all of the previously matching events. Somewhat similar to the example [here, in the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/cep.html#conditions).

The second iterative condition returns true if `size("distinctPorts") >= 9` and this event also has yet another distinct port.

See [this Flink Forward talk](https://www.slideshare.net/FlinkForward/flink-forward-berlin-2017-kostas-kloudas-complex-event-processing-with-flink-the-state-of-flinkcep) ([youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-to8DRtHt0&list=PLDX4T_cnKjD0JeULl1X6iTn7VIkDeYX_X&index=17&t=0s&app=desktop)) for a somewhat similar example at the end of the talk.

If you try this and get stuck, please ask a new question, showing us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the info . So the same value computation can be done with flink match_recognize, can you please elaborate how the distinct port numbers in the second criteria can be matched in Flink

Comment: I've expanded my answer. If you find it helpful, I would appreciate it if you accepted it.

Comment: Thank for the detailed feedback on this regard.

Comment: Using this query returns ip duplicated with the other ips as well. Is there any method by which we can produce only non overlapping ips

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: The above query returns overlapping subset of results, my requirement is that ip entries once returned in the query should not be matched again

Comment: The problem I’m having is let us consider a pattern 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.2 192.168.2.1192.168.2.2 192.168.2.1192.168.2.2 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.2 192.168.2.1192.168.2.2 Suppose I want to match the pattern with two occurrences so I should get the each ip 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.2.2 exactly 5 times . Ie I need the distinct patterns

Comment: Sure. And that's what the query does.

Comment: Apologies for stacking on questions . But is it possible to match the distinct ports as in the port scanning attack using cep. As mentioned by you I’m now aware that brute force can be implemented by the grouping of ips using the groupby method . I’m aware this can be done in sql as you have mentioned for port scanning also.So now what I am not sure is if distinct as in port scanning can be done by using the flink-cep.

Comment: Ok, I've responded again. Now please, let's move on to another question if you want to follow-up further. And if you would kindly up-vote and/or accept this answer, that would be appreciated.